# How to ask to repeat a phrase?

Tags: conversation, telephone

If voice during phone conversation become gibberish, how to ask a person to repeat last words? I'm living in Cyprus and all local people when speak English just use 'tell me' for this. It this a correct way?

Comment: There is already a post on this: [How to politely ask someone to repeat what they said after they've already repeated it once?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/1261/how-to-politely-ask-someone-to-repeat-what-they-said-after-theyve-already-repea) This might help you.

Comment: What is "correct" is a matter of etiquette and local convention. If that is what people say in Cyprus, it must have some degree of acceptance in Cyprus; in Canada, it would be rather confusing or rude.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is correct but doesn't sound good while speaking to someone. Using "pardon me" or maybe "sorry, come again" can be really polite and a good way to ask to repeat their last sentence.